# Error related to " SameSite ", POST method call in Laravel 9

Tags: post, session-cookies, laravel-9, samesite

In a project written with Laravel 9, I needed to connect with a banking portal, I encountered the following **error** on the Callback:

```
https://javadheidarpour.com/sap/CallBack
[HTTP/1.1 419 unknown status 1122ms]

Cookie “remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d” with the “SameSite” attribute value “Lax” or “Strict” was omitted because of a cross-site redirect. CallBack
Cookie “XSRF-TOKEN” with the “SameSite” attribute value “Lax” or “Strict” was omitted because of a cross-site redirect. CallBack
Cookie “nobt_mn_session” with the “SameSite” attribute value “Lax” or “Strict” was omitted because of a cross-site redirect. CallBack
```

---

file config/session.php :

> 'same_site' => "lax",

Answer (score 0):

Callback path defined in **routes/api.php** ect:

```
 https://javadheidarpour.com/api/sap/CallBack
```